# python: how to remove '$'?

Tags: python

All I want to do is remove the dollar sign '$'.  This seems simple, but I really don't know why my code isn't working.

```
import re
input = '$5'
if '$' in input:
    input = re.sub(re.compile('$'), '', input)
    print input
```

Input still is '$5' instead of just '5'!  Can anyone help?

Comment: `$` has its owning meaning in RegExes

Comment: Noooo wonder. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Try using `replace` instead:

```
input = input.replace('$', '')
```

As Madbreaks has stated, `$` means match the end of the line in a regular expression.

Here is a handy link to regular expressions: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Why?  This doesn't answer the question, it provides an alternative approach.  Why not explain why op's approach *doesn't* work?

Comment: @Madbreaks Well, you did attest to this in the comments.

Comment: Sure, but a good answer will explain why the sample code provided by op doesn't work.  If there's a good alternative (which yours is) it may also suggest that.  But you haven't answered the question, you've simply provided a work-around.

Comment: @Madbreaks: Why don't you just write your own answer?  It seems like you have the knowledge to write an answer, you're not satisfied with other answers, you don't want to edit other answers even though you have 2k rep...

Comment: @DietrichEpp Because this happens far to much *in my opinion* on Stackoverflow.  People provide work-arounds but don't address the question to help the asker fundamentally understand what the mistakes are they're making.  That's not what this site is about, at least I don't feel it is.  So when I see that happening I point it out.

Comment: Please feel free to edit away @Madbreaks, this is a *community*.

Comment: @Madbreaks: What you're doing in this question happens far too much in my opinion.  Rather than taking responsibility for sharing your knowledge with the community, making other people say it for you is just a way of satisfying the ego.  **The "edit" button is there for a reason.**

Comment: That's not the point.  You have a 2.2k rep.  Maybe I've been here a little longer, and I can help *you* be better at answering questions.  Or maybe not.  But that's my intent.  No offense intended.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Sorry you see it that way.  I share plenty with this community, and provide answers where I can.  Surprise!  I'm not a Python guy.  I didn't know the answer (how to escape properly in Python).  But I *understood the fundamental problem* which I think any good answer should help the user do.  "Use `replace` instead", to me, isn't a good answer...so I pointed it out.  I believe that's ok.

Comment: @Madbreaks: Please read the [Vote Down](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) page which explains that "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing."  In particular, do not downvote an answer just because it's not thorough enough to satisfy you.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Fair enough, I will keep that in mind.  There, you just helped me be a better SO'er, I hope that I can pay it forward.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, I'd use `str.translate`

```
>>> '$$foo$$'.translate(None,'$')
'foo'
```

And for benchmarking purposes:

```
>>> def repl(s):
...     return s.replace('$','')
... 
>>> def trans(s):
...     return s.translate(None,'$')
... 
>>> import timeit
>>> s = '$$foo bar baz $ qux'
>>> print timeit.timeit('repl(s)','from __main__ import repl,s')
0.969965934753
>>> print timeit.timeit('trans(s)','from __main__ import trans,s')
0.796354055405
```

There are a number of differences between `str.replace` and `str.translate`.  The most notable is that `str.translate` is useful for switching 1 character with another whereas `str.replace` replaces 1 substring with another.  So, for problems like, I want to delete all characters `a,b,c`, or I want to change `a` to `d`, I suggest `str.translate`.  Conversely, problems like "I want to replace the substring `abc` with `def`" are well suited for `str.replace`.

Note that your example doesn't work because `$` has special meaning in regex (it matches at the end of a string).  To get it to work with regex you need to escape the `$`:

```
>>> re.sub('\$','',s)
'foo bar baz  qux'
```

works OK.

Answer (score 2):

$ is a special character in regular expressions that translates to 'end of the string'

you need to escape it if you want to use it literally

try this:

```
import re
input = "$5"
if "$" in input:
    input = re.sub(re.compile('\$'), '', input)
    print input
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dollar sign - otherwise python thinks it is an anchor http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

```
import re
fred = "$hdkhsd%$"
print re.sub ("\$","!", fred)
>> !hdkhsd%!
```

Answer (score -1):

Aside from the other answers, you can also use [`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
input = input.strip('$')
```

Comment: @Madbreaks `All I want to do is remove the dollar sign '$'.`

Comment: @Madbreaks No offence taken, it is definitely an answer to `how to remove '$'` imo. It is *not* a workaround.